Angular Migrating RouterModule to ProvideRouter (standalone approach)
I am trying to migrate my angular app to standalone approach, everything is expected except some routing issues
have routes like this
const routes: Routes = [
    ...[':product/:id/:step', ':product/:id'].map((path: string) => (
        {
            path,
            loadComponent: () => import('./components/form-page/form-page.component').then((m) => m.FormPageComponent),
            data: { forwardToResourceRoute: false },
            resolve: {
                transactionConfig: TransactionConfig,
            },
            canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateFormPageGuard],
        }
    )),
    {
        path: '',
        loadComponent: () => import('./components/form-page/form-page.component').then((m) => m.FormPageComponent),
        data: { forwardToResourceRoute: true },
        resolve: {
            transactionConfig: TransactionConfig, // navigating new url inside resolver :product/:id/:step
        },
    }
]

with old approach this works fine using RouterModule with useHash: true
now migrated to ProvideRouter
  provideRouter(
     routes,
     withHashLocation(),
  )

now i don't receive my query params like before, need a param id to navigate to another url with in resolver but getting empty urlTree
what does it really change here, by removing withHashLocation() then i get my params as expected but need hashing stratagy
did not find better way to navigate directly without component in empty path, may be there is a better way to do this by removing some duplication code (currently FormPageComponent using twice)
does anyone have better idea to handle this and fix hash location stratagy
thx in advance

sounds like a bug in a router with hash location strategy. is there a reason of not using default strategy = history api?

It's required for internal reasons, consumers are requesting hashing urls

somehow this is not an issue, able to fix this with extend locationStrategy https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33000
I was also thinking about remove hash strategy and try to replace url where we have # with empty string
